# Deserializing elements and arrays

Tags: xml, vb.net, arrays, deserialization

i'm having a problem to deserialize a XML to my class. It was working fine until a put the array **det** within the class.

I put a watch just after the deserialization occurs (data = Ctype(...)), and i can see that all the informations were loaded (ide, emit, dest) correctly except for the **det** element: The **det** whose *nItem=1* attribute is loaded, but **det** whose *nItem=2* attribute is not.

With the watch, i could see that the object was loaded like a **single variable**, not a **vector** as i specified in the property declaration.

Any suggests? Thank you!

**Below is where the deserialization happens when the button is clicked:**

```
Protected Sub btnDes_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDes.Click
        Dim data As New nf

        'DeSerializacao XML
        Dim Deserializer As New Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(nf))
        Dim DataFile As New FileStream(Server.MapPath("App_Data\pedro.xml"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)

        data = CType(Deserializer.Deserialize(DataFile), nf)
        DataFile.Close()
        DataFile.Dispose()

 End Sub
```

**Below is part of my XML code**

```
<NF>
                <iNF>
                        <ide>
                                <cUF>31</cUF>                           
                        </ide>
                        <emit>                          
                                <xNome>Tradimaq  Ltda - MG</xNome>                              
                        </emit>
                        <dest>                          
                                <xNome>GEMAQUINAS LTDA</xNome>                          
                        </dest>
                        <det nItem="1">
                                <prod>
                                        <cProd>3.04.000000109</cProd>                                   
                                </prod>                         
                        </det>
                        <det nItem="2">
                                <prod>
                                        <cProd>3.01.580048839</cProd>                                   
                                </prod>

                        </det>

                </iNF>          
</NF>
```

### **Below is part of the class i created to receive the deserialization:**

```
Public Class NF

    Public Property iNF As infNFe

    Public Sub New()


    End Sub

End Class
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Class iNF


    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Property ide As ide
    Public Property emit As emit
    Public Property avulsa_info As avulsa
    Public Property dest As dest

    Public Property det() As det


End Class
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Class det    

    <XmlElement("prod")> Public Property prod As prod

    Public Sub New()


    End Sub

End Class


Public Class prod

    Public Property cProd As String   

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

End Class
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Public Class ide
    Public Property cUF As String
End Class

------------------------------------------------------------------------

Public Class emit
    Public Property xNome As String
End Class

------------------------------------------------------------------------

Public Class dest
    Public Property xNome As String
End Class

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I don't get your code. Wich language is it? Where is the logic to parse the XML?

Comment: sorry... will edit it. It's written in VB.net

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
Public Property det() As det
```

into this:

```
<XmlElement("det")> Public Property det As det()
```

Although I'm not sure why using an XmlElementAttribute will work while omitting it will fail.

Notice that

```
Property det() as det
```

is not a property of an array of det, the parantheses are used for the parameter list which in this case is empty. For a property of an array you'll have to put the parantheses at the end:

```
Property det As det()
```